# Update if "Email already exist" in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a Candidates object model in Django Application, who I get from a form in a Front End.

If this Candidate send personal data again with the same email, DRF response *{"email":["A user with that email already exists."]}* and not save the form.

The idea is, if this candidate send the form again with personal email and I have saved it in my database, I will update personal data of this candidate.

I tried with:

My view:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST','PATCH'])
def CandidatesCreate(request, *args, **kwargs):
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

if request.method == 'PATCH' or request.method == 'POST':

    serializer = CandidatesSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance, created = serializer.get_or_create()
        if not created:
            serializer.update(instance, serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My Serializer

```
class CandidatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

cv = serializers.FileField(required=False,max_length=None, use_url=True)

class Meta:
    model = Candidates
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'user',
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'whatever',
        'whatever'
        )
```

However, it not working.I am not be sure if get_or_create() was depreciated, to be honest. I not found real information about it.

Answer (score 8):

You have "unique=True" on the model's e-mail field, correct?
If so, I think the serializer checks if that's the case when you run:

```py
serializer.is_valid()
```

To overcome this, you can try adding this to the serializer's Meta class:

```py
extra_kwargs = {
    'email': {'validators': []},
}
```

And if you want to keep the email validation, you can try:

```py
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

class Meta:
    #... your code
    extra_kwargs = {
        'email': {'validators': [EmailValidator,]},
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure that this validation is being run against the db. It's more like the [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/). Django tries to parse Http params into python dict and checks their type. Database validation comes when `.save()` is called and on `.is_valid()`. Moreover, [`EmailValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#emailvalidator) checks if the given string is an email regex and not if it exists in the db

Comment: @dstrants , yes, you are correct, I showed how he can remove the unique validator on the serializer level. The model's validators are not impacted by this.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, the solution was this:

```
from .models import Candidates
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

# first we define the serializers
class CandidatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

cv = serializers.FileField(required=False,max_length=None, use_url=True)

class Meta:
    model = Candidates
    fields = (
        'pk', 
        'user',
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'whatever'
        )
    extra_kwargs = {'email': {'validators': [EmailValidator,]},
  }
```

And my view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST','PATCH'])
def CandidatesCreate(request, *args, **kwargs):
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

if request.method == 'PATCH' or request.method == 'POST':

    serializer = CandidatesSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        instance, created = Candidates.objects.update_or_create(email=serializer.validated_data.get('email', None), defaults=serializer.validated_data) 
        if not created:
            serializer.update(instance, serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As also [this solution suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393253/6648243) you can use `update_or_create` instead of `get_or_create` like:

```
# make sure you use the arguments the right way
instance, created = serializer.update_or_create(email=validated_data.get('email', None), defaults=dict_with_everything_else) 
# instead of
instance, created = serializer.get_or_create()
```

just make sure you pass the arguments the right way. When can also check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) on how to do so

Comment: The problem was that update_or_create is not used by serializers, so I used the Model Object. I write the solution below.