# How do I make an upsert using the drf serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to find a clean way using DRF serializers strictly in order to perform an upsert, aka inserting when the object with an indexed column does not exist or updating if it does exist (on duplicate equivalent of sql). I have found other ways using django objects but it seems there is no clear way to do that using a serializer.

Comment: Check if this question helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833307